# Change image displayed using JavaScript via radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I've got my site set up as follows:

```
<h1 class="testTitle"> Letter Height</h1>

<h2 class="testIns">Press the buttons to make it shorter or taller!</h2>  

<div id="testBox">

    <img src="images/height/heightMid.gif"> 

</div>

<form method="get" action="width.php" class="testAns" id="heightAns">
<input type="radio" name="height" value="short" onchange="ChangeDisplay();">-25%
<input type="radio" name="height" value="mid" onchange="ChangeDisplay();">normal
<input type="radio" name="height" value="tall" onchange="ChangeDisplay();">+25%

<br>

<h2 class="confirm">Does this look good?  If so, please click the "Submit" button.</h2>

<span class="submit"><input type="submit"></span>
</form>
```

And I've got a JavaScript function that should be changing the image in  based on the selected radio button:

```
function ChangeDisplay(){
    switch(document.test.field.value){
       case "short":
         document.getElementById("testBox").innerHTML = "<img src='images/height/heightMinus25.gif'>";
         break;
       case "mid":
          document.getElementById("testBox").innerHTML = "<img src='images/height/heightMid.gif'>";
          break;
       case "tall":
          document.getElementById("testBox").innerHTML = "<img src='images/height/heightPlus25.gif'>";
          break;

    }
  }
```

However, when I select the buttons, the display does not change. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you select "document.test.field.value"?

Comment: May I ask where you got the "document.test.field.value" bit? Your form is not called "test" and your series of radio buttons is called "height".

Comment: @user3452790 Can you tell us if any of the answers solved your problem? If so, accept the answer. If not, let us know the status.

Comment: @AbuSulaiman Yep that did it!  I just needed to change that to an actual value.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to the following:

```
onclick="ChangeDisplay(this.value);"
```

and

```
function ChangeDisplay(val){
    switch(val){ ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should fetch the value of your radio button group like this:

document.forms[0].height.value

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use JavaScript to change the background image. Here's an example:

HTML

```
<div id="imgCont"></div><P>
<input type="radio" id="imgBtn" onclick="ClickMe();">Click Me
```

CSS

```
      #imgCont {
     background-image:  
      url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
 }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  function ClickMe () {
  if (document.getElementById("imgBtn").checked == true) {
```

document.getElementById("imgCont").style.backgroundImage="url(http://www.bizreport.com/2011/02/03/android-logo-200x200.jpg)"
      }

```
  }
```